# How to format file system of a specific size in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, format

How to format a file system in Linux. 
Lets say I have a partition /dev/sda3 which is 3GB of size but in my case I would like to 
format only 2Gb of space and mount it. So while running mkfs.xfs -size=2g /dev/sda3 I am getting an error. 
Can someone advise on this ?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to resize/split/recreate the partition first to make 2G partition.

Comment: That is not an option in my case since partition is imported to the client system.

Comment: then perhaps LVM is way to go. Make the 3GB partition LVM, and create a logical XFS file system for 2GB on the volume. I don't think you can simply create 2G XFS on 3G partition.

Comment: Interesting idea, it will definitely work. Thanks guys for your inputs

Comment: Refer to [`man mkfs.xfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.xfs)"In its simplest (and most commonly used form), the size of the filesystem is determined from the disk driver."

Answer (score 1):

You have to use resize2fs command for that purpose (To change the size of file system) 
1> formate the filesystem 
 mkfs.xfs .ext3 /path/ or mkfs -t .ext3 /path/ 
2> then resize ot to size you want
resize2Fs -L 2GB /dev/sda3